# Titanium and using your own databases

Tags: mongodb, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have been recently using Titanium javascript SDK for native app development and it is fun as it is powerful. However I cannot find any examples on using databases like Mongodb or PostgresSQL. Appcelerator encourages you to use their Arrow DB service which is not ideal. I know how to set up my own databases locally and on my own dedicated hardware and want to use them instead. The closest Mongo library I found for Titanium was back in 2012 and only had support for MongoHub and MongoLab.

How can I connect to and use Mongo in Titanium apps?

Comment: you need to build API's to talk to databases basically... an app should never directly talk to an external database. You can use SQLite inside the app though

Comment: That's a good point. I forget web servers are not like apps. Everyone will have an app. Not everyone will have access to the web server.